# Getting JSON into my controller through AJAX: What am I missing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc

I have

```
    // fbi: Files batch info

    $.ajax({
        xhr: function() {
            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
            return xhr;
        },
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("AddFilesToDB","FileUploadAsync")',
        data:  JSON.stringify(fbi),
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(retInfo) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(retInfo));
        }
    });
```

How do I refer to the result of JSON.stringify, an object like

```
'{org:"someOrganization",cat:"someCategory",fileNames:[somepic.jpg,somepaper.docx]'
```

from inside my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> addFilesToDB (???)
{
    ??? Want to use the value of data
}
```

I know this is probably an obvious question, but I'm new to this stuff

Comment: Create a model with properties `string Org`, `string Cat` and `string[] Filenames` so the model will be bound with your data.

Comment: And should an element of that model type be the parameter to the function?

Comment: @EdwardSnowden, the method would then be `public async Task<JsonResult> addFilesToDB (yourModel model)`. Note also you do not need `.stringify()` - just `data: fbi,` should work

Comment: Edward Snowden would know something like this >.>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here goes the solution, first create a model `FileData`

```
public class FileData
{
    public string org { get; set; }
    public string cat { get; set; }
    public string[] filenames { get; set; }    
}
```

Then create an action as shown below -

```
public JsonResult PostFileData(FileData filedata)
{
     return Json("True");
}
```

Then in the view your JQuery code should be -

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            var roles = ["somepic.jpg", "somepaper.docx"];

            var model = new Object();
            model.fileNames = roles;
            model.cat = "business";
            model.org = "news";

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("PostFileData", "Home")",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify({ filedata: model }),
                success: function (data) { alert(data); },
                failure: function (errMsg) {
                    alert(errMsg);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<input type="button" value="Click" id="btnSubmit" />
```

When you click on the `btnSubmit`, all the values will be posted to the above action and with a breakpoint it should be like shown below -

[image]